# Style of an <a> link takes time to apply (firstly it shows without style)

Tags: html, css

I've created a link that acts as a button to logout from a user's account (wordpress) and added some style to it, but I can't figure out why the style takes some time to apply.
This is the html:

```
<div class="cerrar-sesion">
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ); ?>">CERRAR SESIÓN</a>
</div>
```

And this is the style:

```
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
}
.cerrar-sesion{
    padding: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2%;
    right: 2%;
    border: solid;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #000000;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

UPDATE: (Since the problem is already SOLVED, I've removed the link to my website).
Here's the [CODE](https://jsfiddle.net/MrPolymath/odz36hv7/).

Comment: i have seen the code and css code is in the index page. put all the code in the separate css file and add it on head section using **<link rel="stylesheet" href="file_name.css">**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will notice that on your fiddle the problem is not reproduced.

That is because the styles are being added in the wrong place on your site and not in the fiddle. Your style /style section needs to be in your header and not down with all of the scripts at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that your html code is before your css code, so the website loads your html code first, before applying the style to it. So in order to fix it, just switch the positions of the html and css around.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are also right, but @Chris L answered 2 minutes faster so I must give his anwer as the correct one.